# How do I write a bash alias that replaces !$ with the previous command’s last word?

Tags: bash, alias, command-history

I have a script named `cpodin` that copies several build artifacts to another directory. Afterward, I edit `SHA1SUM` in the destination directory.

For example:

```
cpodin /foo/bar/baz
vim !$/SHA1SUM
```

How do I make the latter command an alias named `fixsha` that takes no argument and edits `SHA1SUM` in the directory named by the previous command’s last argument? An alias of

```
alias fixsha='vim !$/SHA1SUM'
```

results in attempts to edit `!$/SHA1SUM` instead of `/foo/bar/baz/SHA1SUM`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not perform history expansion after alias expansion, so you have to do so explicitly using `history`, documented in [Bash History Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins) and excerpted below.

> `history -ps args`
>
> - `-p`
>   Perform history substitution on the *args* and display the result on the standard output, without storing the results in the history list.
> - `-s`
>   The args are added to the end of the history list as a single entry.

An alias of `alias fixsha='vim $(history -p !$)/SHA1SUM'` will work most of the time but not as intended when `!$` expands to a path that contains whitespace. Adding double-quotes around the path argument will protect any escapes on whitespace and results in `vim "/foo/bar\ baz/SHA1SUM"` rather than the desired `vim /foo/bar\ baz/SHA1SUM` or its equivalent `vim "/foo/bar baz/SHA1SUM"`.

So in addition to explicit history expansion, `eval` is also necessary to unwrap one layer of quoting.

```
alias fixsha='eval vim "$(history -p !$)/SHA1SUM"'
```

**Note:** You may be surprised to learn that the double-quotes in the above alias definition are unnecessary. This is because no whitespace is between the expanded value of `!$` and `/SHA1SUM` to trigger bash’s word splitting. However, I like them being there to emphasize the intent that it is expanding to a single argument.